# Possible incorrect use of Pointers in ctypes. Unable to get expected response

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Given the following c code snippet

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "mcp2221_dll_um.h"

int main(void) {
    wchar_t LibVersion[10];
    int response = 0;
    int error = 0;

    response = Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(LibVersion);

    if(response == 0) {
        printf("Library (DLL) version: %ls \n",LibVersion);
    } else {
        error = Mcp2221_GetLastError();
        printf("Version can't be found, version: %d, error %d\n", response, error);

    }
}
```

with the function signature as defined in mcp2221_dll_um.h file

```
MCP2221_DLL_UM_API int CALLING_CONVENTION Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(wchar_t *version);
```

I compile the source using gcc: `gcc -o test test.c -L. -lmcp2221_dll_um_x64`
and run the executable: `./text.exe`
then I get the following output: `Library (DLL) version: 2.2b`

**GREAT** it works as expected!

Now I would like to use **python** and **ctypes** to produce the same results.
So I wrote the following python code snippet

```
from ctypes import *

library = WinDLL("./mcp2221_dll_um_x64.dll")
library.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion.restype = c_int
library.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion.argtypes = [POINTER(c_wchar_p)]

LibVersion = c_wchar_p()

results = library.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(LibVersion)

print("results: ", results)
print("LibVersion: ", LibVersion)
```

and run the code: `python test.py`
and get the following output

```
results: 0
LibVersion: c_wchar_p(27584762469223794)
```

The results 0 tells me the request was successful, but I am not sure how I can convert the LibVersion into a readable string which equals **2.2b** like I get from running the c sample.

**Please help me out here, I am using pointers the wrong way? or some other mistake?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c_wchar_p` is a pointer and equivalent to `wchar_t*` in C.  Just use `.argtypes = [c_wchar_p]`.

Another issue is the API being called is using the `wchar_t*` buffer as an out parameter, so you need to allocate a buffer to pass.  This should work:

```
from ctypes import *

library = WinDLL("./mcp2221_dll_um_x64.dll")
library.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion.restype = c_int
library.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion.argtypes = c_wchar_p,

LibVersion = create_unicode_buffer(10)
results = library.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(LibVersion)

print("results: ", results)
print("LibVersion: ", LibVersion.value)
```

Note that `LibVersion.value` displays the null-terminated Unicode string in the buffer.  If you needed to access the raw data you can use indexing or just copy the whole array out to a string with slicing:

```
>>> s=ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(10)
>>> s
<ctypes.c_wchar_Array_10 object at 0x000001E63085C7C8>
>>> s.value
''
>>> s[:]
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```